# MySQL error #1064, i not think: what What to do with this?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

```
MySQL error in file: /engine/modules/files/newfiles.php at line 14
Error Number: 1064
The Error returned was:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `version`, `alt_name` FROM `dle_` WHERE `approve` = '0' AND `date` < '2014-08-28 12:57:32' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,
```

code fragment:

```
 $db->query ( "SELECT `id`,
 `title`,
 `version`, 
 `alt_name`
 FROM `".PREFIX ."_".$modul_dbtitle ."` WHERE `approve` = '0' AND `date` < '{$thisdate}'  ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 0,".$filesConfig ['numbernewfiles'] ."");
```

Comment: Please do *not* use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: LIMIT 0 is meaningless remove it

Comment: Make sure that the `numbernewfiles` column is an `int` and that there is indeed a value being passed through `$filesConfig`. Plus, if your column's name is indeed `numbernewfiles` and not `Numbernewfiles` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

`$modul_dbtitle` apparently does not have a value as your tablename is incomplete in your query.

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `version`, `alt_name` FROM `dle_` WHERE `approve` = '
                                                  ^^^^^^
                                                   HERE
```

You need to figure out why. My guess is you are missing an `e` in the variable name:

```
$modul_dbtitle
```

should be

```
$module_dbtitle
```

Additionally, `$filesConfig ['numbernewfiles']` also contains no value and will break your query.

You should ensure [error reporting is turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) as I suspect PHP would be warning you about these errors.

Comment: No, the problem is not in the letter e... Need other variant.

Comment: Your issue is still the same. That variable has no value. You need to figure out why.

Comment: `$filesConfig` that's a variable we don't know about, or how it's being populated from @TheZimbabvEE Please show mode code in your question and how it's being brought/fetched in.

Comment: @JohnConde Even with OP's answer (must've got the wrong impression) with the code is using, it's still unclear. `_config_global.php` - tempted to vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing the number of line in your statement:

```
LIMIT 0,".$filesConfig ['numbernewfiles']

DESC LIMIT 0,
           ^^^^^
```

Looks like `$filesConfig ['numbernewfiles']` is blank

Comment: But the error does not affect the empty variable ... no?

Comment: @TheZimbabvEE Sorry but i do not unstand what you want. after the ',' you need a value. If you add one, the syntax is ok.